# How to click search field in play store android appium?

Tags: java, selenium, appium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqQh7.png)I cant click google play store search field

How can i click and sendkeys search field play store.

```
AndroidDriver driver;

@AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.EditText[contains(@text,'Uygulama ve oyun arayın']")
public AndroidElement searchField;

public AndroidElement searchField;

public void click_searchField() {
                
        searchText.isDisplayed();
        searchText.click();
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure your driver is not null.
2. Try to find the search field by CSS Like this:

- ```
  android.widget.EditText[*]
  ```

Or

- ```
  android.widget.EditText[]
  ```

Or by Xpath:

- ```
  //*[@value='Uygulama ve oyun arayın']
  ```

Comment: I get error Unable to locate element. I guess  need to use ui selector.  I don't know how to use

Comment: @reverseengineer Can you add an image showing the elements attribute. If you can't upload an image - add the element full tag with all attributes.

Comment: Thank you Tal Angel